# How can I create an .xls file with a readwrite password from Delphi

Tags: delphi, excel

I know that it is possible to create .xls files from Delphi using ADO, OLE automation with Excel and even using several commercial libraries.

My requirement now is not just creating a new .xls file and adding data to it but in addition protecting it with a password against editing.

I guess this would be possible using OLE automation but that would require an Excel installation on the computer and also add all the potential hassle of OLE automation which I would like to avoid.

Does any of the other solutions provide the option of password protecting the file?

(Yes, I know this is far from secure, but the customer requests it.
Just in case it matters: I am using Delphi 2007.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page is from the help file from the NativeExcel Suite:
Protect method

> ```
>  Protects a workbook so that it cannot be modified.                   
>
>  Syntax     
>
>     procedure       Protect();     
>     procedure       Protect(   Password     : string);   
>
>      Password          
>                     Optional string. A string that specifies a  
>                     case-sensitive   password for the
>                     workbook. If this argument is 
>                     omitted, you can unprotect the workbook without
>                     using a password . Otherwise, you must specify the 
>                     password to unprotect the workbook.
>   Example       
>
>     This example sets the password for the workbook.       
>
>         workbook.Protect('mypass123');
> ```

NativeExcel has worked very well for me.